# DIY 3D laser scanner with ROS

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to do SLAM with low-cost hardware. I've considered using an ultrasonic-sensor but read that it's not possible to do SLAM  with a 1-point range sensor. Then I found [fabscan](http://hci.rwth-aachen.de/fabscan) which is a DIY 3D laser scanner. I'll like to ask if it's possible to do this ? If someone has tried it before ? and how to go about the integration with ROS?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306419/diy-3d-laser-scanner-with-ros/) by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2018-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The intended use of FabScan seems to be stationary short-range 3D scanning of static objects. Each scan is probably going to take a relatively long time to complete. For these reasons, it won't be the right scanner for you.

For the most common SLAM algorithms (such as gmapping or Google cartographer), you only need a 2D laser scanner, not a 3D laser scanner.

On the turtlebot, a RGB-D camera like the Microsoft Kinect, Asus Xtion Pro Live (unfortunately no longer available) or Orbbec Astra is used to simulate a 2D laser scanner using one of these two packages:

http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan

http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan

This is probably going to be your best bet - those 3D cameras are relatively cheap.

There are also low-cost 2D laser scanners such as the RPLIDAR. The main advantage over a 3D camera is the bigger field of view (360° instead of 60°), but I would try a 3D camera first.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2018-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2018-10-22**:
Would be hard pressed to find a cheaper or simpler scanner than neato botvac laser scanner with aftermarket mount and controller. I use on indoor robot and am really pleased with it. https://www.getsurreal.com/product/botvac-lidar-sensor-mount-package/

And No. I am not affiliated with that website.

**Comment by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on 2018-11-09**:
do you know if this sensors can work in direct sunlight and under rain ? I found

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2018-11-09**:
I do not know about in the sun. Indoors it has range of maybe 5 meters.
It would need a major upgrade to be suitable for use in the rain.